# Rotation of spin operator itself

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, commutator, rotation

Consider for example the rotation of the $x$ component of spin by $\pi$ about the $z$ axis. This flips the spin giving $$e^{i\pi S_z}S_xe^{-i\pi S_z}=-S_x.$$
However, can this be proved directly using the commutation relation $[S_z,S_x]=iS_y$ and expanding the exponential?

As $[S_x,[S_z,S_x]]\neq 0$, I cannot use the usual formula to simplify it, but I am hoping there might be a similar formula which requires something like $[S_z,[S_x,[S_z,S_x]]]=0$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we consider the function
$$
f(\lambda)  = e^{\lambda A} B e^{- \lambda A},
$$
and consider the Taylor expansion of $f(\lambda)$ around $\lambda = 0$, then the observation that $f(0) = B$, and
$$
\frac{df}{d\lambda} = [A,f(\lambda)], \\
\frac{d^2f}{d\lambda^2} = \left[ A, \frac{df}{d\lambda} \right] = [A,[A,f(\lambda)]],
$$
etc., we find
$$
e^{\lambda A} B e^{- \lambda A} = B + \frac{\lambda}{1!} [A,B] + \frac{\lambda^2}{2!} [A,[A,B]] + \frac{\lambda^3}{3!} [A,[A,[A,B]]] + \cdots.
$$

Now consider the special case where
$$
[A,[A,B]] = \beta B,
$$
which is true for the problem you are interested in.
This results in a simplification where all terms collapse into terms proportional to either $B$ or $[A,B]$. Explicitly,
$$
e^{\lambda A} B e^{- \lambda A} = B + \frac{\lambda}{1!} [A,B] + \frac{\lambda^2}{2!} \beta B + \frac{\lambda^3}{3!} \beta [A,B] + \frac{\lambda^4}{4!}  \beta^2 B + \cdots \\
= B \left\{ 1 + \frac{(\lambda \sqrt{\beta})^2}{2!} + \frac{(\lambda \sqrt{\beta})^4}{4!} + \cdots \right\} + \frac{[A,B]}{\sqrt{\beta}} \left\{ \frac{\lambda \sqrt{\beta}}{1!} + \frac{(\lambda \sqrt{\beta})^3}{3!} + \cdots \right\}.
$$
Then you can compare this to the Taylor series for the hyperbolic functions, obtaining
$$
e^{\lambda A} B e^{- \lambda A} = B \cosh (\lambda \sqrt{\beta}) + \frac{[A,B]}{\sqrt{\beta}}\sinh (\lambda \sqrt{\beta}).
$$
In your case, $A = S_z$, $B = S_x$, $\lambda = i \pi$, and $\beta = 1$. By just plugging into the above formula, you quickly find
$$
e^{i \pi S_z} S_x e^{-i \pi S_z} = -S_x.
$$

Answer (score 7):

As you know, $\vec S= \vec \sigma /2$, [so that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector)
$$
e^{i\pi \sigma_z/2} = i\sigma_z, ~~\leadsto \\
\sigma_z   \sigma_ x   \sigma_z  =- \sigma_x    .
$$

This holds for *all* representations, since the spin 1/2 irrep is faithful, and the above is a group-theoretic identity, adjoint action. This is to say that, since the object is in the Lie algebra (see below), the combinatorics in all representations will be strictly *identical* to the above spin 1/2 case, and *need not be carried out explicitly*!

If you insist on summing the entire series in the standard [Hadamard lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula),
$$
e^A B e^{-A}= B + [A,B]+ [A,[A,B]]/2! + ...
$$
the recursively nested commutators are also straightforward to compute.

Comment: Isn't this only for spin half?

Comment: ***No***! You also learned that group theoretic identities for faithful representations hold for *all* representations. In your case, the adjoint transform of $S_x$...

Comment: OK, true, but still you have not answered my main question of how it can be proved using the commutation relation.

Comment: Direct application of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula) of course, also covered in class, hopefully. This is the *point* of adjoint action, in case you count the legs of the centipede and divide by a 100.

Comment: But I insist that you slipped into an XY problem: the proper way to prove many-many of these statements is by the doublet --> all irreps trick I showed you.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind.

Comment: Important to. Has saved the day in several contexts. Lots of books (with the honorable exception of Gilmore's) skip it, or consider it obvious. Note the relations has to be in the group, *not* in the universal enveloping algebra.